# Is it possible to push a navigationController as a subView of UIApplication

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, subview

does anyone know if it's possible to push navigationController as a subView of UIApplication.

For instance like this

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]addSubview:[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES]];
```

This doesn't work of course else I wouldn't have asked the question;).

But something like this. It would be great if I could do this because then it means that I can push this view on top of my movieplayercontroller object.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[self presentModalViewController:rvController]
```

This will replace whatever view you currently have set with the view associated with rvController